# Unable to require directive in AngularJS 1.5 component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.5

I've created a directive which works perfectly fine. Now after bumping `angular` to `1.5.0`, I figured this directive is a typical example of what could be written using the new `.component()` notation.

For some reason, the `require` property no longer seems to work.

The following is a simplified example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.component('mirror', {
  template: '<p>{{$ctrl.modelValue}}</p>',
  require: ['ngModel'],
  controller: function() {
    var vm = this;
    var ngModel = vm.ngModel;
    
    ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(onChange);
    ngModel.$render = onChange;

    function onChange() {
      vm.modelValue = ngModel.$modelValue;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <input ng-model="someModel"/>
  <mirror ng-model="someModel"></mirror>
</div>
```

I also tried using `require` as a simple string:

```
...
require: 'ngModel'
...
```

and as an object:

```
...
require: {
  ngModel: 'ngModel'
}
...
```

I've looked at the docs for [$compile](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/docs/api/ng/service/$compile) and [component](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/docs/guide/component), but I can't seem to get it to work.

How can I require other directive controllers in an AngularJS 1.5 component?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Angular 1.5's component syntax, you don't have access to the required controllers until the component's `$onInit` lifecycle method is called. So you need to move your initialisation into there, here's a working version of your snippet where I added the `$onInit` function.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.component('mirror', {
  template: '<p>{{$ctrl.modelValue}}</p>',
  require: {
    ngModel: 'ngModel',
  },
  controller: function() {
    var vm = this;
    
    vm.$onInit = function() {
      var ngModel = vm.ngModel;
      ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(onChange);
      ngModel.$render = onChange;
    };
    
    function onChange() {
      vm.modelValue = vm.ngModel.$modelValue;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <input ng-model="someModel"/>
  <mirror ng-model="someModel"></mirror>
</div>
```